# Understanding the correctness of the Euler Tour Technique

Tags: graphs, parallel-computing, eulerian-paths

I can't prove the correctness of the following algorithm by R. E. Tarjan amd U. Vishkin, as described [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique):

> Given an undirected tree presented as a set of edges, the Euler tour
>   representation (ETR) can be constructed in parallel as follows:
>
> We construct a symmetric list of directed edges:
>
> - For each undirected edge $\{u,v\}$ in the tree, insert $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ in the edge list.
> - Sort the edge list lexicographically. (Here we assume that the nodes of the tree are ordered, and that the root is the first element in
>     this order.)
> - Construct adjacency lists for each node (called ''next'') and a map from nodes to the first entries of the adjacency lists (called
>     ''first''):
> - For each edge $(u,v)$ in the list, do in parallel:
>
>   - If the previous edge $(x,y)$ has $x \neq u$, i.e. starts from a
>       different node, set $first(u)=(u,v)$
>   - Else if $x \neq u$, i.e. starts from the same node, set
>       $next(x,y) = (u,v)$
>
> Construct an edge list (called $succ$) in Euler tour order by setting
>   pointers $succ(u,v)$ for all edges $(u,v)$ in parallel according to
>   the following rule:
>
> $ \mathrm{succ}(u,v)=\begin{cases}
>                   \mathrm{next}(v,u) & \mathrm{next}(v,u)\neq \mathrm{nil} \\
>                   \mathrm{first}(v)&\text{otherwise}.
>                  \end{cases}$

Why the edge list constructed in the last step is an Euler tour? What theorem or lemma gurantees that every single edge is visited?